# stackdriver Custom Metrics

Tags: google-app-engine, stackdriver

I would like to monitor CloudSQL, GCS, GAE, and GCE using a custom metric in the stack driver

I am wondering how to apply a custom metric to monitor the stack driver.

Can I see the stack driver as a language that I need to write using Api related to custom metrics?

I would like to know if there is another way.

Comment: What do you want to monitor? Some GAE metrics is already in stack driver. Another way for what?

Comment: @marcadian You are using the appengine (flex-custom) environment.
flex-custom was deploy by installing nginx, php, etc. in the docker.

I want to see a detailed log of installed nginx.
Can I monitor nginx logs deployed to appengine (flex-custom) without creating custom metrics?